# Variation problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many strings (no longer than 8 letters) can be created from letters A, B and C so that the letter B appears as many times as A and C appear together?

I realised that if letter A appears i times, and B appears k times, then C has to appear k-i times. But since a problem takes in consideration strings of length 0-8 I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Nice, so your string will have $2k$ of length. 
**Hint:**
What if you go $k=0,1,2,3,4.$ Notice that fixing $k$ you have to **choose** $k$ spots for $B$ and then you are free to place $A'$s and $B'$s in $2^{2k-k}$ ways.